# Quando è possibile l'elisione e troncamento della preposizione "di" sia nello scritto che nella pronuncia?

Tags: verbs, grammar, pronunciation

Mi vengono in mente le seguenti frasi:

1. Credo di avere chiamato Alessia
2. Credo d'avere chiamato Alessia
   (Elisione)
3. Credo di aver chiamato Alessia
   (Troncamento)
4. Credo d'aver chiamato Alessia
   (Elisione e Troncamento)

Come da titolo, vorrei sapere se in questi casi è possibile e corretto elidere e/o troncare questi verbi sia nello scritto che nella pronuncia e se ci sono dei casi in cui è grammaticalmente scorretto.

Grazie a tutti in anticipo e buona serata

Comment: IMO, they are all acceptable in speech, but in writing we would normally choose 1 or 3.